# How to hide the 2nd and 4th table row using css or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Its a dynamic code and i would like to hide second and 4th tr of the table using table id HMP_options. How to achieve this?

```
<table id="HMP_options" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td align="left" colspan="2">
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <input></input>
                 <tbody>
                    <tr><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td></td></tr>    /* this tr i want to hide */
                    <tr><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td></td></tr>   /* this tr i want to hide */
                 </tbody>
           </table>
        </td>
       </tr>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use this CSS rule:

```css
#HMP_options table tr:nth-child(-2n + 4) {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZXjWV/

Since this is IE9+ you might want to make jQuery help it.

In this example I assumed that you want **only** hide 2nd and 4th row. If you want to hide 6th, 8th and so on as well you should use `:nth-child(2n)` rule.

Comment: much better... I got it!! +1

Comment: `.HMP_options > table` won't match anything -- the inner table isn't a child of the outer one.  If you lose the `>`, it might work...

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
.HMP_options > table td:nth-child(2),
.HMP_options > table td:nth-child(4) { display:none;}
```

Comment: A very small change you need to make, change `td` to `tr`, as its about rows. `.HMP_options > table tr:nth-child(2),
.HMP_options > table tr:nth-child(4) { display:none;}`, But better than jQuery... +1

Comment: Why td:nth child, i want to access the 2nd child of the table which is tr

Comment: `.HMP_options > table` won't match anything -- the inner table isn't a child of the outer one.

Answer (score 1):

Using css:

```
.HMP_options tr:nth-child(2), .HMP_options tr:nth-child(4){display: none;}
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('.HMP_options tr:nth-child(2), .HMP_options tr:nth-child(4)').css('display','none');
```

Comment: But class name should be use here because there are so many tables in the code its dynamic code so it should uniquely identify the table

Answer (score 0):

> Use eq in jquery . Select the element at index n within the matched
>   set. Zero-based index of the element to match.

```
 $("tr:eq(1),tr:eq(4)").hide();
```

Comment: But class name should be use here because there are so many tables in the code its dynamic code so it should uniquely identify the table